# Proxy setting in Ionic version 4+ for Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, proxy, cors

I am developing hybrid app for Android using Ionic 5 in local environment and so I tried to set up the proxy config as following below.

In command line
**$ ionic config set proxy http://myserver.com**

changed ionic.config.json file:

```
{
  "name": "appName",
  "integrations": {
    "capacitor": {},
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "type": "angular",
  "proxy": "http://myserver.com"
}
```

But it didn't work and please help me with this issue.

**Note:
I know already proxy configuration for Angular project as below, but it didn't work in Android app.**

```
"options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
          }
```

Comment: Please check following docs.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/faq/cors, 

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cors-error-on-device-ionic/108333